# confusion between clang and llvm

Tags: clang, llvm

I think i know the difference between clang and llvm but at the same time i am confused. I understand clang is the front-end which will take the program and do hexing-parsing-ast creation and then creating an IR(LLVM IR).

And then LLVM, as the backend, takes this IR, optimizes it and creates assembly for the target architecture. Is that correct ? 
I also read that llvm does not have a linker. So how is that handled on OS X ? Also how do i look at the assembly generated by llvm ?x

Answer (score 2):

> And then LLVM, as the backend, takes this IR, optimizes it and creates assembly for the target architecture. Is that correct ?

What you've described there all sounds pretty correct, except that for several target architectures, LLVM actually generates binaries directly, without having to go through the intermediate assembly-printing stage.

> I also read that llvm does not have a linker. So how is that handled on OS X ?

You use the system linker, `ld`.

> Also how do i look at the assembly generated by llvm ?

Either disassemble the output binary (with `otool`, for example) or use `clang -S` to generate assembly rather than binary output.

Comment: Note that LLVM is working on a linker and it is already semi-functional: see http://lld.llvm.org.

Comment: It's not the system linker for any popular toolchain yet, is it?

Comment: It is part of the LLVM ecosystem, so eventually (it's not in a usable state yet) it will probably become Clang's default linker. Eventually here means within 1 and infinity years from now.